# Reprocess AWS SQS Dead Letter Queue messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm sending messages that failed in my lambda to a dead letter queue using aws sdk. I want to wait for few hours before sending the message back to the main queue for reprocessing. I have a lambda attached to my dead letter queue. I can use delay for sending messages to the dead letter queue. But the maximum delay is 15 minutes. But I want to wait for more time. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS is **not intended to be used in this manner**. Its primary purpose is to store messages and then provide them back when requested.

Some other options:

- Store the message in a database and have the application search for relevant messages based on a timestamp field, *or*
- Do some tricky stuff with delays on AWS Step Functions (which has a delay feature)

Comment: I'm exploring both these options. Thanks.

Comment: For now, I have implemented the db approach. I'm storing the failed messages in dynamodb and reprocessing them in a lambda function which is triggered by a cloudwatch event. I'm curious to explore the Step Functions approach at a later point in time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46502397/788833) you can extend the delay, by giving each message a timestamp and processing only those that are in queue for a while now.

```
message = SQS.poll_messages
if message.perform_message_at > Time.now
   SQS.push_to_queue({perform_message_at : "Thursday November 
   2022"},delay:15 mins)
else
   process_message(message)
end
```

Comment: That referenced answer doesn't look like a particularly good idea. It is retrieving messages from the queue, then sending a new message back if it is too 'early'. That's a lot of overhead, with the potential for lost messages if things go wrong.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yep, it involves some overhead