# How to delay retry by 4 hours on SQS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, scheduling, spring-jms

**TL;DR:** how to mimic [rabbitMQ's scheduling functionality](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2015/04/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq#:%7E:text=To%20delay%20a%20message%20a,queues%20or%20to%20other%20exchanges.) keeping the consumer:

1. stateless
2. free from managing scheduled messages
3. free from useless retries from scheduled messages between receiving the message and finally consuming it the correct scheduled time

I have a single SQS queue with default properties on creation. The average time a consumer takes to process a message is 1~2s. But a few messages needs to be processed twice, between a 4h window. These messages are called B, and the others are called A.

Suppose I have my queue with the following messages: `A1, A2, B1, A3, B2` (5 messages, max 10s to consume them all) at the start of these table:

```
time     | what should happen
---------|-------------------
now      | consumer connected to queue
now+10s  | all As were consumed successfully and deleted from queue
           Bs had their unsuccessful first try and now they are waiting for their retry in 4h
between  | nothing happens since no new messages arrived and old ones are waiting
now+4h4s | Bs successfully consumed during second retry and due that, deleted from queue
```

I have a `Spring` application where I can throw exceptions when I find a type `B` message. Due simplicity and scalability, I want to have one single thread consuming messages taking 1~2s to consume each message.

This way, I cannot hang message processing [as this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32532414/3026886). I also don't need SQS' `Delivery delay` since it postpones just the messages arriving at queue and not retries. If possible, I would like to keep using long polling `@JmsListener` and avoid at all keeping any state on my memory's application. I [want to avoid this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) if possible

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Comment: @BookOfZeus unfortunately this don't suit me since `The maximum is 15 minutes`. I want a 4h delay

Comment: then have a counter on your queue item and reinsert every 15 minutes 15 times ... when it reach 15, you have waited 4 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a small AWS Lambda function that gets invoked every ~minute.  That function would get a message (off the hopefully FIFO-type SQS queue) and check the time it was added.  If it was added >= 4 hours, it would delete it off the incoming queue and add it to the delayed by 4 hour queue, which your application could listen to.  If it moved a message, continue to do so until the next message isn't 4 hours old.  Increase/decrease the frequency of the lambda to increase the granularity of how 'tight' to 4 hours you are, but at the added expense of running the lambda more often.

Here is a quick link to an example of an AWS Lambda function using SQS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html

Answer (score 2):

You could send message B to a Step Functions state machine and put a wait state in to wait for 4 hours before sending it to the queue. The state machine would keep the state for you, and you can [send messages directly to SQS from Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sqs.html) so you don't need to write any code.

Comment: since I want a 4h delay, and the maximum `DelaySeconds` is 15min, this step function would be called 4h/15min = 16 times?

Comment: No, step function is called only when the state of the execution changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using `JmsListener` with `setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)`, I decided to run this at the end of the consumer of re-processable messages:

```
myAmazonSqsInstance.sendMessage(
        new SendMessageRequest()
                .withQueueUrl("queueName")
                .withMessageBody(myMessageWithText)
                .withDelaySeconds(900) // 900s = 15min
);
```

This way this message will be consumed successfully but a new message with the same body will be produced on the queue. This message will be consumed in 15min, and due to my business logic, fail again. There will be 16 fails (16*15min=4h) til it finally is consumed without producing new messages.

Although this is not what I asked for, and it's similar to the other answers (only the tech stack is different), I decided to write it down here to make a java solution available

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and robust way is, Have a timestamp attribute of when it can be processed and use delay window to hide it for 30 mins. When the message is not ready to consume(i.e. timestamp is less than current time), keep it back to SQS again if the time not reached, else process it.